# How to get changed data from FOR EACH STATEMENT without transition tables

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, postgresql-11

I would like to write a trigger with FOR EACH STATEMENT. This trigger will listen multiple events and I don't use transition tables in my trigger.

So, can I get the change data with the code below?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION on_delete_update_employee_ref()
    RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM employee_ref
    WHERE id in (SELECT ins_upd_del.id
                  FROM  TG_TABLE_NAME ins_upd_del
                  WHERE ins_upd_del.employee_type = 'new');
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$;


DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS on_delete_update_employee_ref ON employee;
CREATE TRIGGER on_delete_update_employee_ref
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON employee
    FOR EACH STATEMENT
    EXECUTE FUNCTION on_delete_update_employee_ref();
```

Comment: You either need to use the transition table or a row level trigger.

Comment: I only need to use FOR EACH STATEMENT. And in my trigger, I don't define something like `REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS inserted` because I listen three events in one trigger. So, I would like to confirm that I can combine three triggers and use `TG_TABLE_NAME ` as the changed data table?